# word file (doc, docx) damaged after encryption and decryption

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, aes

i have tried the following code to encrypt and decrypt files using asp.net c# rijndael managed. all of the images notepad is encrypted and decrypted successfully, when it comes to doc or docx file it always showing damaged file when i tried to open. but if i click resolve this issue in microsoft word, then the file is back. what could go wrong in the code. please help me

```
    public void EncryptFile(string password, string inputFile, string outputFile)
    {

        try
        {

            UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
            byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password.Trim());

            string cryptFile = outputFile;
            FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(cryptFile, FileMode.Create);

            RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt,
                RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, key),
                CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);

            int data;
            while ((data = fsIn.ReadByte()) != -1)
                cs.WriteByte((byte)data);


            fsIn.Close();
            cs.Close();
            fsCrypt.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception err)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(err);
        }
    }

    public void DecryptFile(string password, string inputFile, string outputFile)
    {
        try
        {


            UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
            byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password.Trim());

            FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);

            RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt,
                RMCrypto.CreateDecryptor(key, key),
                CryptoStreamMode.Read);

            FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create);

            int data;
            while ((data = cs.ReadByte()) != -1)
                fsOut.WriteByte((byte)data);

            fsOut.Close();
            cs.Close();
            fsCrypt.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception err)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(err);
        }

    }
```